# Help finding inverse Fourier transform of a function.

Tags: fourier-series

I have the function $f(x) = 1 -|x|$ for $|x|\leq 1$. And zero everywhere else. I'm supposed to find the inverse Fourier transform of the function but I only have a formula for the inverse Fourier transform of a vector not a function in my notes.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried reading this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)?

Comment: @Avatar Are you trying to find the Fourier transform of the function $f(x)$ that you have there? Otherwise what do you mean by taking the inverse fourier transform of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in question was $sinc^2(x)$ according to the grader; not sure where they got that but there it is.